# Is a fully connected layer equivalent to Flatten + Dense in Tensorflow?

Tags: matlab, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

A fully-connected layer, also known as a dense layer, refers to the layer whose inside neurons connect to every neuron in the preceding layer (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_(deep_learning)#Dense_layer)).

In the MATLAB Deep Learning Toolkit, when defining a `fullyConnectedLayer(n)`, the output will always be (borrowing the terminology from Tensorflow) a "tensor" of shape 1×1×n.

However, defining a dense layer in Keras via `tf.keras.layers.Dense(n)` will not result in a rank 1 tensor depending on the input, [as explained in the Keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense):

> For example, if input has dimensions (batch_size, d0, d1), then we create a kernel with shape (d1, units), and the kernel operates along axis 2 of the input, on every sub-tensor of shape (1, 1, d1) (there are batch_size * d0 such sub-tensors). The output in this case will have shape (batch_size, d0, units).

*Am I correct in assuming that what MATLAB does in `fullyConnectedLayer(n)` is equivalent to cascading a `Flatten()` layer and a `Dense(n)` layer in Tensorflow?* By equivalent I mean that exactly the same operation is performed.

It would appear that this is the case based on the number of weights that MATLAB requires for a `fullyConnectedLayer`. The weights in fact are n×M where M is the dimension of the input ([see MATLAB Documentation: "At training time, Weights is an OutputSize-by-InputSize matrix"](https://it.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/nnet.cnn.layer.fullyconnectedlayer.html)). In fact snooping around the internals of this MATLAB function, it seems to me that the InputSize is precisely the size of the input if it were "flattened", i.e. `M = a*b*c` if the input tensor has shape `(a,b,c)` (and of course I experimentally verified this by multiplying).

The layer I'm trying to build is towards the final stages of a categorical classifiers, so I need the final output of the Keras model to be of shape `(None, n)` where `n` is the number of labels in the training data.

Comment: Yes, You are right. FullyConnectedLayer is equivalent to cascading a Flatten() layer and a Dense layer in Tensorflow. Please check this [reference](https://indiantechwarrior.com/fully-connected-layers-in-convolutional-neural-networks/) for more details.